# WooCommerce pay per photo upload

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

So the thing is, I want to develop a plugin that can do this integrated with WooCommerce:

One goes inside website, click to "buy a product" and then can uoload one or more photos, paying per photo uploaded?

The concept here will be a photo contest and people can submit multiple photos but they have to pay per photo that they upload.

In order to achieve this, I am thinking in counting each file uploaded and then increment the quantity on that product, so then I have a product with a certain price that is incremented in quantity each time one uploads a photo.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this more efficiently?

EDIT:

Found this plugin that will suite this purpose, so I don't need to develop it on my own saving me time: [WooCommerce Drag & Drop Uploader](https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-drag-drop-uploader-ajax-file-upload/21067299)

Comment: Asking to recommend a product (plugin, theme, book, hosting provider), tool, library or off-site resource is out of scope of the site, as it attracts opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @Mat Thank you for your input. I appologise for missleading the question and going against policy. I will then edit this later after I start development if I have any question, othersiwe I will just answer this myself so others with same question can see the resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know about plugins, but if you develop it yourself, then the process might be to have a 'buy now' type button that people pay for, then, on completing the transaction, they are sent a special upload link with a query parameter in the URL that allows them to upload a file.

Your code would have to generate and store the special query parameter (random guid type of value), then (on loading that page) verify the parameter as being valid (and not being used before). On successful upload, the code would diasble (inactivate) that guid so it couldn't be used again.

You will have to figure out how to use transaction processing on PayPal (or whatever payment provider) so that your 'thanks for the order' page would generate the stored guid/parameter.

Good luck!

Comment: Seems an idea to me! :) Thanks a lot for your input, although I already got -2 for this type of question! hehe

Comment: Glad I could help. I don't necessarily agree with the policy on plugin recommendation questions, but I don't run this place. I just answer questions that I can help with...